# The principle of structural induction in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Propositional logic and first-order logic are theories in ZFC. The principle of structural induction is a theorem of ZFC. Is that what justifies the usage of structural induction in propositional logic and first-order logic?

By *justifying* I really mean proving, that is, tracing back to axioms.

Meaning of structural induction: [Sturctural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort-of true, with a caveat. I would put it like this: the principle is a theorem of ZFC, so that is one way to justify its use in proving theorems about proposition calculus, likewise predicate calculus.

As the Wikipedia article mentions, structural induction is a special case of a general result about well-founded partial orders. The formulas of proposition logic form a well-founded partial order under the "is a subformula of" relation. Likewise for predicate calculus (aka first-order logic).

So as applied to the predicate calculus, this would be a proof that first shows something is true for atomic formulas, then shows that if it is true for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma(x)$, then it is true for $\neg\alpha$, $\alpha\wedge\beta$, and $\exists x\gamma(x)$. And then concludes from this that it holds for all formulas. Similarly with the propositional calculus. Here the base case is propositional variables, and you still have the connectives, but you don't have to worry about quantifiers or terms.

Note that I am talking about proving results *about* the propositional (or predicate) calculus. For example, showing that every formula of propositional logic has an equivalent in disjunctive normal form, or that every formula of first-order logic has an equivalent in prenex normal form. Or a particularly simple example you mentioned: that every formula has equal numbers of left and right parentheses.

In contrast, a proof *in* one of these calculi is a different beast. As an example, consider [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Proofs_in_propositional_calculus) of the formula $A\to A$, in two versions of the propositional calculus. You'll see that no axioms of ZFC appear. Indeed, it's impossible even to *express* the axioms of ZFC in the propositional calculus: quantifiers and the relation symbol $\in$ are essential.

This "about vs. in" distinction is an example of metamathematics vs. mathematics. A formal system, like the predicate calculus, consists (from one viewpoint) just of strings of symbols with rules for manipulating them. We can apply ordinary mathematical reasoning to this "symbol manipulation game". But the predicate calculus itself is formalized reasoning. So we have two layers, the so-called mathematical layer (namely proofs *in* the calculus), and the metamathematical layer (proofs *about* the predicate calculus). And likewise for the propositional calculus.

What sort of reasoning is permissible at the outer metamathematical layer? In principle, any kind of reasoning that would be allowed elsewhere in mathematics. The justification for such reasoning isn't different just because the subject matter is predicate calculus, instead of (say) number theory or group theory.

So now the question becomes one of formalization in general. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272210/why-is-it-important-that-mathematics-can-be-formalized-in-set-theory) has a couple of good answers. I would say briefly, formalization in ZFC became the "gold standard" of rigor during the 20th century. But on the one hand, much of math requires less than the full strength of ZFC. This is true for the examples in the fourth paragraph above. The subject matter is very concrete, just finite strings of symbols. At heart not much more is involved than plain old induction.

On the other hand, reasoning can be completely convincing, even rigorous, without being translated into the formalism of ZFC. Personally, if I saw a formal proof in ZFC of any of the examples above, it would not strengthen my belief in the truth of these results.

Comment: So, as I understand it, the axioms of ZFC are assumed in propositional logic. And since structural induction is a theorem that can be proved from the axioms of ZFC, we can use it as a proof technique for theorems in propositional logic.

Comment: No, I wouldn't put it that way. As @spaceisdarkgreen remarked, you are mixing up the mathematics with the metamathematics. You can use structural induction to prove theorems *about* the propositional calculus, but it is not used *in* proofs in the propositional calculus. Nor are any of the axioms of ZF used inside the propositional calculus. If this still isn't clear, could you give an example of a proof *in* the propositional calculus that uses structural induction?

Comment: Say, that every wff has an equal number of open and closed brackets.

Comment: Okay, good examples. The bracket statement is **about** the prop. calc. It's not a theorem **in** prop. calc. As for the alphabet, that's just a set; I don't see how union is needed. But even it were, that's also not a theorem in the prop. calc. For an example of a proof **in** two versions of prop. calc., see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Proofs_in_propositional_calculus

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “built upon”, but theorems about the prop. calc., like nearly all theorems in modern math, can be formalized in ZFC. (Although you generally need way less than the full strength of ZFC to prove stuff about prop. calc.)

Comment: This will probably be kicked to chat soon, so I’ll sign off now.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, to reflect your rewitten question.